# birt report get values of url parameters

Tags: reporting, birt

I'm trying to pass url parameters FirstName and LastName with a submit form. It works well except I don't know how to access the viables to add them to the filter.

[Submit Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPjfH.png)

[Adding to filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTXVo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **params["firstname"].value** to access URL parameter at run time.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hScQ0.png)

Find sample rptdesign here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r7VvSBDCFUGp5gzab5_CflJ_ArvQA8VA/view

Comment: I tried params["firstname"] but i will try params["firstname"].value but I thought they were the same.

Comment: Okay I found my issue. I have to add them as Report Parameters before I can use them as variables.

Comment: Nice! You can refer the attached rptdesign file. I have created dummy table which will be filtered as per URL parameter. If you are fine with solution, please accept/vote it.